# Can I run JUnit 4 to test Scala code from the command line?

Tags: testing, command-line, emacs, scala, junit

If so, how? I haven't come across the proper incantation yet.

If not, what's the best approach to unit-testing Scala code from the command line? (I'm a troglodyte; I use IDEs when I have to, but I prefer to play around using Emacs and command-line tools.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since compiled Scala is just Java bytecode (OK, with a lot more $ characters in class names), it would be exactly as for running JUnit 4 tests against Java code, i.e. from the command line by passing the test classes as arguments to `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`.  As JUnit 4 out of the box only has command line support, you don't even have to worry about suppressing GUI based test runners.

That said, the specific Scala test frameworks (ScalaTest, [ScalaCheck](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/)) do provide a more idiomatic set approach to testing code written in this more functional language.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [ScalaTest](http://www.artima.com/scalatest/).

> ScalaTest is a free, open-source
>   testing tool for Scala and Java
>   programmers. It is written in Scala,
>   and enables you to write tests in
>   Scala to test either Scala or Java
>   code. It is released under the Apache
>   2.0 open source license.
>   Because different developers take
>   different approaches to creating
>   software, no single approach to
>   testing is a good fit for everyone. In
>   light of this reality, ScalaTest is
>   designed to facilitate different
>   styles of testing.

See the [Runner](http://www.artima.com/scalatest/doc-0.9.5/org/scalatest/tools/Runner%24object.html) documentation for how to run tests from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of ScalaTest -- or any of the other Scala-specific frameworks, for that matter, is very good. I'd like to point to something else, though.

[SBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/).

SBT is a build tool, like Ant, Maven or Make. One interesting aspect of it, which will matter to us, is that it is Scala-based. I don't mean it has special capabilities to handle Scala code or that it is written in Scala, though both these things are true. I mean it uses *Scala code*, instead of XML like Maven and Ant, as the configuration source.

That in itself is interesting. Just today I saw a wonderful example of separating test sources from program sources, which I post here just because its so cool.

```
// on this project we keep all sources, whether they be Scala or Java, and whether they be
// regular classes or test classes, in a single src tree.
override def mainScalaSourcePath = "src"
override def mainJavaSourcePath = "src"
override def testScalaSourcePath = "src"
override def testJavaSourcePath = "src"
override def mainResourcesPath = "resources"

// distinguish main sources from test sources
def testSourceFilter =
  "Test*.scala" | "Test*.java" |
  "AbstractTest*.scala" | "AbstractTest*.java" |
  "ScalaTestRunner.scala"
def mainSourceFilter = ("*.scala" | "*.java") - testSourceFilter
override def mainSources = descendents(mainSourceRoots, mainSourceFilter)
override def testSources = descendents(testSourceRoots, testSourceFilter)
```

But what makes it even more interesting is that SBT works like a console. You run "sbt", and you get dropped into a console-like interface, from which you can type commands like, for instance, "test", and have your tests run.